# Обработка параметра `address=` блока `phantom`

Tags: яндекс-танк

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
При настройке танка с использованием `phantom` в параметре `address=` мы задаем непосредственно адрес мишени. Вэб-сервер настроен таким образом, что доступ к нему осуществляется по нескольким адресам одновременно. Имеется ли возможность задать в параметре `address=` сразу несколько адресов одной мишени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

несколько адресов задать в параметре `address` нельзя, да и не понятно, по какому принципу в этом случае ротировать ip адреса, но зато можно сделать несколько секций `[phantom]`, в каждой указать свой адрес мишени, ленту и схему нагрузки. Возможно это то что вам нужно.

PS: [пример нескольких секций phantom-а](https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#multi-tests)

Comment: Т.е., в таком случае фантом будет одновременно нагружать вэб-сервер по обоим адресам или последовательно - сначала по одному, а затем по другому?

Comment: Одновременно. Как только одна из секций завершит работу, весь мультитест остановится.